# PHP Call to a member function on a non-object debuging

Tags: php, oop, debugging

I try to init my object in a class but I get  Call to a member function edit_column() on a non-object and I try to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Practically I'm using 2 classes one is acting as a controller and second one as model. The code above

```
<?php

//Model
class MyClass {

    public $columns = array();
    private $edit_columns = array();

    public function select($columns) {
    //do select
    }

    public function from($table) {
    //from
    }

    public function add_column($args) {
    //add_column
    }

    public function edit_column($column, $content) {
        $this->edit_columns[$column][] = array('content' => $content, 'replacement' => explode(',', $match_replacement));
        //return $this;
    }

}

//Controller
class MyOtherClass {

    function some() {

        include('MyClass.php');
        $table = new MyClass();
        //I try to init my Class as it follows
        $table->select('id', 'name')
                ->from('mytable')
                ->edit_column('my arguments')
                ->add_column('my arguments');
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: You are forgetting quotes in from, edit_column and add_column.

Comment: Can you show us the complete code for the methods in MyClass?

Comment: try MyOtherClass extends Myclass and use myclass method?

Comment: To chain you need to `return $this;` on end of each method.